# Cannot load jupyter after Anaconda installation

Tags: anaconda

Got the following error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 9, in
import sqlite3
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3_*init*_.py", line 57, in
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 83, in
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 12, in
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On windows by downloading: the sqlite3 dll  https://www.sqlite.org/download.html (find your system version)

And placing it into the folder: C:\Users\YOURUSER\Anaconda3\DLLs

(Depending on how you installed Anaconda, this may have to be placed into the following folder: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs)

OR

Locate the path of sqlite dll in - `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Library\bin` or whatever your installation location is, then Add this to PATH in environment variables, and it should work then.